# Time and space complexity analyzation of meet and middle attack of triple DES

Tags: block-cipher, meet-in-the-middle-attack

How can we analyze the time and space complexity of meet and middle attack on a Triple-DES?

Comment: What kind of triple-DES (112 or 168 bits of key)? That will make it a duplicate of [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/2466/555) or [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/6345/555), I guess.

Comment: Welcome to [cryptography.se]. This seems a dump of an HW or maybe not, however, we have Q/A for this. Even you can see the related links on the right.